# How to Update one column (point) in php sql

Tags: php, sql

Please help me to write full code in php and sql to update only (point) in table below.

table name : tuser

```
id_user : 12
name : lisa
username : lisa1990
password : User123
point : 12930
```

Comment: *Please help me to write full code in php and sql to update*?

Comment: `UPDATE tuser SET point = 'whatever' WHERE id=12;` There you go, have fun.

Comment: UPDATE tablename SET columnname = value WHERE condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy...

```
$con = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$command = "UPDATE tuser SET point='your value' where id=whatever";
//replace 'your value' with the new value and "whatever" with the user id
mysql_query($command);
mysql_close_connection($con);
```

Next time don't ask so stupid questions here... use Google